# Volume expressed as a Double Integral in rectangular coordinates

Tags: calculus

Volume expressed as a Double Integral in rectangular coordinates of $z=-{(x^2 +y^2)}^{-1/4}$

I don't get what to do with this textbook question either, sorry still on phone... I want volume  underneath $z = -1$ , so bounds are $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ same with $y$ at $z=0$ Pretty sure

But it is only filled to $z=-1$ so I need to get the integral to be from $x$ and $y$ that take only the volume under $z= -1$

$x = \pm \sqrt{ 1 - x^2}$ and reverse $x$ and $y$ is what I feel the bounds are but how do I set this up as the region for integration?

I just want to set up a double integral for the equation, for z less than or equal to z=-1

Comment: Sorry I am on a phone

Comment: @Ron gorden  fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are going to want to integrate the function within the unit circle centered on the origin, since $ \ z \ $ is just equal to -1 on the circle and less than that within the circle.  The integrand has four-fold symmetry about the origin, so you can integrate over $ \ x \ $ from 0 to 1, and from 0 to $ \ \sqrt{1-x^2} \ $ for $ \ y \ $ , as you seem to be describing, and then multiply the result by 4.  Here is a graph of the surface described by the integrand: it does "run down to negative infinity" on the $ \ z-$ axis.

[image]

Since the surface lies "below" the $ \ xy-$ plane, the integration will give a negative result; if you want to represent the value as a volume, you would take the absolute value.  Although the surface "descends forever", your value *will* be finite.  (Integrating in polar coordinates makes short work of this calculation.)

Comment: I didn't do much -- you had it mostly sorted out already...